# inotifywait shell script run as daemon

Tags: linux, shell, sh, inotify, inotifywait

I have a script that watches a directory (recursively) and performs a command when a file changes. This is working correctly when the monitoring flag is used as below:

```
#!/bin/sh

inotifywait -m -r /path/to/directory |
    while read path action file; do
            if [ <perform a check> ]
            then
                my_command
            fi
    done
```

However, I want to run this on startup and in the background, so naïvely thought I could change the -m flag to -d (run inotifywait as daemon, and include an --outfile location) and then add this to rc.local to have this run at startup. Where am I going wrong?

Comment: in your `/etc/rc.local` file, did you call the script with a single `&` at the end?

Comment: @Jebby - this is exactly what I needed to do. Thanks! Running inotifywait as daemon was a red herring, as was pointed out by tink below the code was never run. If you set this as an answer, I will mark it as the correct one.

Comment: I have added the answer below. Glad to help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to add a single `&` to the end of command in your `/etc/rc.local`

Putting a single `&` at the end of a command means ***Run this program in the background so the user can still have input.***

Answer (score 5):

[Incron](https://linux.die.net/man/8/incrond) is  a cron-like daemon for inotify events.

Just need to use [incrontab](https://linux.die.net/man/5/incrontab) and an entry for your task:

```
/path/to/directory IN_ALL_EVENTS /usr/local/bin/my-script $@ $# $%
```

And **/local/bin/my-script** would be:

```
#! /bin/bash
local path=$1
local action=$2
local file=$3
if [ <perform a check> ]
then
  my_command 
fi
```

Comment: This doesn't answer his question, or offer an alternative solution.

Comment: Is it better now?

Comment: I’ve read Incron won’t watch a directory recursively so this is why I didn’t try it. I’ll give your solution a try and see. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

Well .... with **-d** it backgrounds itself and outputs **ONLY** to outfile, so your whole pipe & loop construct is moot, and it never sees any data.

Comment: Thanks, that explains it. Does this mean that inotifywait can only log changes with the -d flag? Is it possible to trigger an action after a change occurs?

Comment: @Nicholas : No, it doesn't mean that. But if you specify --outfile it doesn't output anything but debug info to standard output.  If you want to interact with the output **AND** have a log just use tee ... ` inotifywait -m -r /path/to/directory | tee -a ~/notify | while ... `

Comment: ah I see, that makes much more sense now. I achieved what I needed above, but using the inotifywait daemon flag would be a more elegant solution. I will give this a go using tee. Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: Most welcome.  You could split processing up, daemonise inotifywait and have the log being read in a second step, but that would introduce a) more complexity and b) potential timing issues on startup.  There's nothing wrong with the **KISS** approach and using tee for what it's intended for ;}